# JavaEmbeddedFrame tray while starting Spark chat application

Tags: openjdk

I'm  getting a JavaEmbeddedFrame tray in my centos7 taskbar whenever I open the Spark Messenger application. This tray I'm not able to close and do any other actions. Is there any way to fix this issue.

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Spark 2.8.3
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Spark seems to be a Java-based application, so perhaps this behaviour is intentional? Does the tray go away when you exit Spark?

Comment: Thank you, Yes it goes once we exit the application. But this behavior was not there in my centos 6 system that's why I looking for a solution for this.